# mongoclient is not working not connecting to port ( The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i tried connecting mongodb to express but i recieved an error i just followed the tutorial which was 3years ago, i use updated or current express and mongo

error connectionTypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
GET /admin/add-product 304 45.510 ms - -

"above is the error in the console "

here is the connection code

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

const state = {
  db: null,
};


const url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

const dbName = "dbname";

const client = new MongoClient(url);


const connect = async (cb) => {
  try {
   
    await client.connect();
 
    const db =client.db(dbName);
    
    state.db = db;
    
    return cb();
  } catch (err) {
  
    return cb(err);
  }
};
const get = () => state.db;

module.exports = {
  connect,
  get
}
```

here is the app.js file (express-generator)

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars')
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var adminRouter = require('./routes/admin');
var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
var db = require('./config/connection')


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.engine('hbs', hbs.engine({ extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layout/', partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/' }))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(fileUpload());
db.connect((err)=>{
  if (err) {
    console.log("error connection"+err);}
    else {
  console.log("succesfully database connected to port");}
})
app.use('/', usersRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Please post the code form `add-product` in your `./routes/admin` file.